# Microsoft.DirectX.DirectXException when playing video in picturebox C#

Tags: video, directx, picturebox, playback

I'm having a problem playing DirectX video in a picturebox control. First I pass the video as a parameter to a child form's constructor:

```
    public Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video TPVideoPlayer;      //This is the player.

    public frmProjectInfo(clsGameInfo GameInfo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if ( GameInfo.blTPVideoPresent == true)
            TPVideoPlayer = GameInfo.vidTPVideo;
     }
```

Next I assign the video to play in a picturebox control:

```
            if (TPVideoPlayer != null)
            {
                try
                {   
                    PanelWidth = pbTPImage.Width;
                    PanelHeight = pbTPImage.Height;
                    TPVideoPlayer = glbvidTPVideo;
                    TPVideoPlayer.Owner = pbTPImage;     //This is where the crash occurs. 
                    pbTPImage.Width = PanelWidth;
                    pbTPImage.Height = PanelHeight;
                    TPVideoPlayer.CurrentPosition = 0;
                    btnPlayTPMedia.Visible = btnPlayTPMedia.Enabled = true;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.ToString(), "oops!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
                    txtbx.Text = e.ToString();
                    txtbx.SelectionLength = txtbx.TextLength;
                    txtbx.Copy();
                }
            }
```

The child form is a dialog. When I click the OK button, the child form closes and the video that TPVideoPlayer is set to is returned to the main form:

```
    public void ShowProjectInfoDialog()
    {
        frmProjectInfo ProjectInfo = new frmProjectInfo(GameInfo);
        if (DialogResult.OK == ProjectInfo.ShowDialog())
        {
            if (ProjectInfo.TPVideoPlayer != null)
                GameInfo.vidTPVideo = ProjectInfo.TPVideoPlayer;
         }
      }
```

Next, when I open the child form using the above method "ShowProjectInfoDialog" my app crashes. Here's the Exception it throws:

```
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectXException occurred
  _HResult=-2147024809
  _message=Error in the application.
  HResult=-2147024809
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Error in the application.
  Source=Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
  ErrorCode=-2147024809
  ErrorString=E_INVALIDARG
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video.set_Owner(Control value)
  InnerException:
```

I can't get the inner exception info because code execution doesn't make it to the "catch" and I can't find anything on the Internet that will explain what exactly is causing the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that ``Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback`` is legacy Managed DirectX 1.1, which has not been updated since ~2006, only officially supports .NET 2.0, and requires the legacy DirectSetup package to deploy. You should look at moving to something else like [SlimDX](https://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Chuck. I'll look into SlimDX and SharpDX.